# CNAME setup displaying 'Bad Request (400)'

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

### Background:

My Django app is located @ `www.name-of-app.rhcloud.com` Through `dns-provider.com` I own: `www.name-of-app.com`

The CName setup is as follows:
`name-of-app.com` redirects to `www.name-of-app.com`, `www.name-of-app.com` is setup as a CNAME alias to `www.name-of-app.rhcloud.com`

Now if I try to access www.name-of-app.com from any browser I receive a 'Bad Request (400)' error.

I have played around with the following settings:

- I can successfully redirect `www.name-of-app.com` to `www.name-of-app.rhcloud.com`, but then after switching back to a CNAME I am met with the same error.
- I have added the necessary alias ala: rhc alias add `www.name-of-app.com` -a myApp
- I have tried the steps of removing && then re-adding the above alias, to no effect.

If I run the host command from my devel station I see that the alias is correctly set up.

cmd: host www.name-of-app.com`(first 2 lines of output are listed below):`www.name-of-app.com`is an alias for`name-of-app.rhcloud.com`.`name-of-app.rhcloud.com`is an alias for`ex-std-nodeXXX.prod.rhcloud.com`.

I am working with `dns-provider.com`, but they haven't raised any issues to this point.

### Question:

How can I get this CNAME issue resolved? It seems to be out of my control and beyond my domain of expertise at the given moment.

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ironically enough the issue turned out to be a Django related problem (someone removed the Django mail list).  Clearly I didn't provide enough information to know that however.

The issue lies in the fact that the CNAME was not enabled in my ALLOWED_HOSTS settings.  Upon adding it to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting, I was able to access the site as expected.

Cheers.

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you elaborate a bit on how you solved it. I have added my domain in ALLOWED_HOSTS '.mydomain.com', but its still gives a 400 error message.

Comment: Should `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` fix this problem? It seems to persist for me event with this.

Answer (score 3):

@Ibn Saeed (I don' t have enough reputation to answer, with a comment)
I had the same issue and solved it adding to ALLOWED_HOSTS the exact domain name leaving it like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.mydomain.com.',
    'mydomain.com'
]
```